# Why does a number appear between the headers and the body in a HttpURLConnection request?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I would like to send a multipart request. Unfortunately the request fails, because the `HttpURLConnection` library inserts a number between the headers and the content, like this:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=*****
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 9; SM-G970F Build/PPR1.180610.011)
Host: localhost:7777
Accept-Encoding: gzip

115
test
```

Why is that number (115) there? How is it possible to avoid that?
This is my simplified code:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:7777");

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);


DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream()));
dos.writeBytes("test");
fileInputStream.close();
dos.flush();
dos.close();
```

Comment: If I had to guess, that's from `DataOutputStream`. I **strongly** recommend that you use a more modern HTTP API for Android app development, such as OkHttp.

Comment: I can not. I run out of memory, because those libraries convert the post data to a byte array before sending it. I would like upload large files, that do not fit into memory. That is why I try it this way.

Comment: Why is that coming from `DataOutputStream` ?

Comment: "because those libraries convert the post data to a byte array before sending it" -- no, they do not. [Here is a blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/07/05/multipart-upload-okttp-uri.html) showing streaming from a `Uri`, for example, in a multipart form upload. As that post shows, we have to do special stuff with OkHttp *because it streams* rather than working with a byte array.